# additional insert after creating new item in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Hello I have created a form page on a table "item1" that is in a Many to Many relation to another table "item2". when inserting a new item1 record through the form I need to insert all related item2 records in the bridge table item1_item2 what I need is to know how to create a function/process to insert these data after creating the item1 record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a new process after the default insert process in the form page. in the new process I get the newly inserted row id and I insert it with the correspondent team id.

Answer (score 0):

You should create Master-Detail page for that.
Press "Create new page", then select "Form", then - "Master-Detail Form". Then you need to choose your master table("item1"), detail table ("item1_item2") and so on. When you will pass all steps of wizard, APEX creates two (or three - it depends on what you will choose) pages, first - for editing your "item1" table, second - for editing related data in table "item1_item2". First page will contain links to second page.
After that you can create Master-Detail pages for editing tables "item2" and "item1_item2".